# Group by function is not working in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have created a `stored-procedure` where I want to execute and display data based on some status and dates. In that Query I am using `GROUP BY` function. But it's giving me error as

> ORA-00904: "TFC"."OFFERED_DATE": invalid identifier

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TFC.SPANID) , TO_CHAR(TFC.MZ_CODE) AS  MAINT_ZONE_CODE,  TO_CHAR(TFC.MZ_NAME) AS  MAINT_ZONE_NAME,
                SUM(TFC.MHO_HANDOVER_CERT) AS NE_LENGTH,
                TFC.CREATED_DATE AS OFFERED_DATE
                FROM APP_LCO.tbl_fip_checklist TFC
   WHERE LENGTH(trim(TFC.SPANID)) > 8
                AND LENGTH(trim(TFC.SPANID)) < 21
  AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
                MINUS
          SELECT TO_CHAR(BB.LINK_ID) AS SPAN_ID,
                TO_CHAR(BB.MAINTENANCEZONECODE) AS  MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
                TO_CHAR(BB.MAINTENANCEZONENAME) AS  MAINT_ZONE_NAME,
                MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH AS  NE_LENGTH,
                BB.CREATED_DATE
                  FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS BB
                  WHERE SPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY'
   group by TFC.SPANID,TFC.MZ_CODE, TFC.MZ_NAME, TFC.MHO_HANDOVER_CERT, TFC.OFFERED_DATE;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `TFC.CREATED_DATE`? You're aliasing that to `OFFERED_DATE`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Tried with both and its not working/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't group by **alias** - you have to use column name, and that's `tfc.created_date`.

You misplaced `GROUP BY` clause; it can't be at the end of the 2nd query (as you use `MINUS` set operator of two `SELECT`s), but the one that contains aggregates - and that's the 1st query:

Apart from that, there's no use in `distinct` in a query that contains `group by` clause.

So:

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid),                 --> remove DISTINCT
         TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code) AS maint_zone_code,
         TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name) AS maint_zone_name,
         SUM (tfc.mho_handover_cert) AS ne_length,
         tfc.created_date AS offered_date      --> column name is CREATED_DATE
    FROM app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist tfc
   WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) > 8
         AND LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) < 21
         AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid),                 --> move GROUP BY here
         TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code),
         TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name),
         tfc.created_date                      --> use column name (not its alias) here
MINUS
  SELECT TO_CHAR (bb.link_id) AS span_id,
         TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonecode) AS maint_zone_code,
         TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonename) AS maint_zone_name,
         maint_zone_ne_span_length AS ne_length,
         bb.created_date
    FROM tbl_fiber_inv_jobs bb
   WHERE span_type = 'INTRACITY'
```

---

**[EDIT]** How to use that query as a source (a CTE) for another `SELECT` statement:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
-- your current query begins here ...
      (  SELECT TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid) spanid,              
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code) AS maint_zone_code,
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name) AS maint_zone_name,
                SUM (tfc.mho_handover_cert) AS ne_length,
                tfc.created_date AS offered_date          
           FROM app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist tfc
          WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) > 8
                AND LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) < 21
                AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid),                     
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code),
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name),
                tfc.created_date              
       MINUS
       SELECT TO_CHAR (bb.link_id) AS span_id,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonecode) AS maint_zone_code,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonename) AS maint_zone_name,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS ne_length,
              bb.created_date
         FROM tbl_fiber_inv_jobs bb
        WHERE span_type = 'INTRACITY')
-- ... and ends here
  SELECT spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         SUM (ne_length),
         offered_date
    FROM temp
GROUP BY spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         offered_date;
```

---

**[EDIT #2]** You commented that you still get duplicate rows; you shouldn't have. Here's a simple example which shows that there are no duplicates:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     temp (spanid,
  3           maint_zone_code,
  4           maint_zone_name,
  5           ne_length,
  6           offered_date)
  7     AS
  8        (SELECT 'MUMB_1208', 'MB01', 'Navi Mumbai', 23, DATE '2023-07-31' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'VDDR_0001', 'DR01', 'Vadodara-1', 3, DATE '2023-06-08' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'VDDR_0001', 'DR01', 'Vadodara-1', 4, DATE '2023-06-08' FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT 'VDDR_0001', 'DR01', 'Vadodara-1', 5, DATE '2023-06-08' FROM DUAL)
 15    SELECT spanid,
 16           maint_zone_code,
 17           maint_zone_name,
 18           SUM (ne_length),
 19           offered_date
 20      FROM temp
 21  GROUP BY spanid,
 22           maint_zone_code,
 23           maint_zone_name,
 24           offered_date;

SPANID    MAIN MAINT_ZONE_ SUM(NE_LENGTH) OFFERED_
--------- ---- ----------- -------------- --------
MUMB_1208 MB01 Navi Mumbai             23 31.07.23
VDDR_0001 DR01 Vadodara-1              12 08.06.23

SQL>
```

Comment: Can't I get the `VDDR_001` value in single row by grouping it ?fyi for img

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRxNY.png

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. That's completely different issue than the one you reported in original question. If you do have another question (related to VDDR_001), ask it. Don't forget to provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: I already asked for `GROUP BY` in my question, and in your answer I can't see group by for whole query. What I want to display is, I don't want same `tfc.SPAN_ID` to be repeated again. I want to combine and display data in single row

Comment: That's because you can't have GROUP BY for the whole query. As I said: I don't understand what you want to get, but - just guessing - perhaps you should use current query as a **source** (CTE?) for yet another SELECT statement which would then aggregate rows by that VDDR_001.

Comment: yes, exactly.. I am not good at implementing `CTE`. can you update your answer and let me know

Comment: Sure; have a look.

Comment: I am still getting multiple records for `VDDR_001`

Comment: VDDR_001 is a SPANID column. There shouldn't be any duplicates. I edited answer and added an example - have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255286/discussion-between-nad-and-littlefoot).

Comment: what is `-- your current query begins here ...` ? do I need to replace this with my query

Comment: any update ?? pls need urgent help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213928/oracle-cursor-is-adding-same-span-multiple-times-in-a-table-via-stored-procedure?noredirect=1#comment136129906_77213928

Comment: No, sorry, nothing new from me. It is impossible for the community to resolve problem unless you post actual sample data that illustrates the issue. If you choose to do that, create simple tables - I saw you posted two of them, but with quite a lot of columns that seem to be irrelevant. Remove everything that isn't necessary for us to reproduce what you are saying.

Comment: can we start discussing on chat so that we can conclude, maybe I have something to present but not able to post here ?